# RestController with AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-restcontroller

My `RestController` :

```
@RestController
public class TeacherRestController {

private static final String TEACHER_MODEL = "teacher";

@Autowired
TeacherService teacherService;

@GetMapping("/rest/teachers/getAll")
public List<Teacher> getAllTeachers() {
    return teacherService.getAll();
}
}
```

Model `Teacher` :

```
@Entity
@ToString
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "teachers", schema = "public")
public class Teacher {
@Id
@Column(name="teacher_id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int teacherId;
@Column(name = "teacher_name")
@NotNull
@Size(min = 4,max = 75,message = "Teacher name should be not less than 4 symbols and not more than 75 symbols!")
private String teacherName;
@Column(name = "position")
@NotNull
@Size(min = 3,max = 50,message = "Teacher position should be not less than 3 symbols and not more than 50 symbols!")
private String position;
```

My `index.html` :

[image]

And `angular.js` :

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

$http.get('http://localhost:8081/rest/teachers/getAll')
    .then(function(response) {
        $scope.myWelcome = response.data;
    });
});
```

On `index.html` teachers doesn't show, but on this address `http://localhost:8081/rest/teachers/getAll` I have teachers in JSON.

[image]

Comment: I do not remember clearly how was in in AngularJS but my feeling is that you don't have the `teacher` object set on the `$scope`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem is in angularjs. Take a look here https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_02

When the data is loading from server you assign it to `$scope.myWelcome = response.data;`

Then you access your data in the template using `teacher.` which iss not defined on the `$scope`.

Try renaming `myWelcome` into `teacher`.

Comment: And he should add ng for for his table data integration